# Hi I am from HR. We are looking for software/program/apps which will help us in sending out emails once a candidate has accepted an offer

Tags: web-apps

Now let me play out a scenario

1. Candidate accepts offer on 13-07-2023, we should send greeting and engagement video/poster via e-mail by 15th July . This has to be an automated process.
   -> IF offer accepted,send e-mail(s)
2. If candidate drops, we must be able to stop any other e-mail in pipeline.

Is there any software which can achieve this ? We are short on funds and therefore would require free/lite version.

We are based out of India.

Much Regards,
Aman Panda